# Merge two branches while destination branch keep out one file from source branch

Tags: git, bitbucket, gitignore

I have two branches that one has specific file which I don't want to go to destination branch during the merge. I put the path of the file in .gitignore file of destination branch, but during the merge, the file came to it.

This is not related to any local computer. This is totally in bitbucket as remote repository. One branch which is merge to destination branch has a file that is in list of gitignore in destination branch.

Is destination branch at bitbucket look at gitignore when merge is happened?
If yes why the file was copy to it?

Answer (score 2):

To take effect of the .gitignore file you must update the index after making changes to .gitignore file

```
git rm --cached .  #removes indexed files

git add .   # adds back to the index while respecting .gitignore file
```

then make a commit and push it to the remote branch

Comment: Did you read my issue? How can I run this command on Bitbucket?

Comment: @navid You cannot run any command directly on bitbucket. You can only push commits from your local machine unless you are merging 2 branches without any conflicts using the web interface of bitbucket.

Answer (score 1):

to add to [@SamuelRobert's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54586526/86072) answer :

`.gitignore` is only consulted when running `git add`,
it is not used at all when running `git commit`, `git merge` or `git push`.

Comment: To add to that further: `.gitignore` does not remove files from commit history.